# Looking for a firefox plugin that will list the input fields by name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, fiddler

I am looking for a firefox plugin that will look at a page and list the forms and the inputs (hidden, text, radiobuttons, checkboxes, etc) that will be submitted with a form submission.  I would like to view these by name.

I am doing ASP MVC development with some very large complicated forms.  currently, the most convenient way of getting a list of fields that will be submitted with a form submit is to submit the form and look at the fiddler traces.  I would like instead, to render the page, then see a list of inputs and their names.  (Because ASP MVC uses the name field for binding).

I am using asp mvc 2.

Comment: does Firebug have this functionality? I use it every day and have not seen anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/).

In the *Forms* menu there is an option to *View Form Information*, which is what you want.

Comment: this works, but the presentation needs polish.